# Input Current for DC DC Converter

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter

I have a supply of 17V@890mA. I am using COTS DC-DC converter, which has efficiency upto 90% at Minimum input voltage and 83% at Max Input voltage. It has input range between 4.25-24V. It provides output at 3.3V@1A.

So what will be the current consumption/Input current requirement of this converter? On what factor it depends?

I couldn't find this info in the DC-DC converter specs.

Comment: Link to specs? What do you mean 17V @ 890 mA - where did that figure come from? This sounds like an assignment. Is it?

Comment: assume it's 83% efficient: to get 3.3W out you need to put 3.3/0.83 in - somewhere around 4W, from 17V ,  4x4 is 16  so about 1/4A

Comment: You can find the calculations in this answer: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/275566/4245 I'm blowed if I am typing them out again.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon No, this is the supply for Led Driver. Not an assignment. It came from calculating Leds and their combinations.

Comment: @Jasen What's 1/4A?

Comment: like 250mA but less precise,

Answer (score 3):

The factors that determine input current are output power, input voltage, and converter efficiency. Power = Voltage x Current. Efficiency = Power Out / Power In. If you know the converter's efficiency *at the voltage and power it is operating at* then calculating the input current is trivial.

But...

> ...which has efficiency **upto** 90% at Minimum input voltage and 83% at
>   Max Input voltage

That's a problem, because it only tells you the *maximum* efficiency the converter can achieve, not what it will be at any particular operating point. Efficiency typically peaks at less than rated output current. Here's an example:-

[Pololu 3.3V, 1A Step-Down Voltage Regulator D24V10F3](https://www.pololu.com/product/2830):-

[image]

At 5V this converter's efficiency peaks at ~93%, but is down to 83% at 1A out. At 24V it peaks at 83%, and is down to 79% at 1A. At 17V we would expect it to achieve about 81% at 1A. Now we can calculate the input current.

3.3V x 1A  = 3.3W out. 3.3W / 81% = 4.08W in. 4.08W / 17V = 0.24A.